# Why do the motors for my Arduino RC car not respond to any command after the first command is received sometimes?

Tags: arduino, dc-motor, remote-control

I'm making a mini RC car with an Arduino nano and wireless communication with RF433, with 2 motors with 2 motor drivers (L293D). I use 4 1.5V batteries to power the arduino nano and another 6V battery pack to power the motors, and use a joystick with an Arduino Mega to send commands. 
I've written a program that sends specific digits when the joystick is in a certain position, i.e. when the joystick is "bent" to the front it sends a "1", a "2" is sent when the joystick is bent towards the back, and so on.

My problem is this: When I bend the joystick towards a certain direction, the RC car moves accordingly without problem; However, when I bend the joystick towards another direction (in other words send a different command), the RC car doesn't respond. 
I took a look at what the RC car was receiving, and I've noticed that after the first command was sent (when I bend the joystick towards a certain direction), no more commands get to the RC car (in other words the Arduino Nano). This occurs occasionally, and I can't afford to have defects like this. I think this means the Arduino Nano "froze" after the first command.
Is this because of not enough voltage or current? Are there any alternatives to 4 1.5V batteries that are not pricey (I need to build 8 of these RC cars)?

UPDATE: These are the pictures of my breadboard and whole thing. Though I doubt it'll help. [image][image]

Comment: Do you have separate power rails for the Arduino vs the motors? Are you certain the batteries are able to deliver the amount of current necessary for the motors (especially the instantaneous in-rush current)? It sounds like the Arduino is suffering a brownout when the motors kick in and cause a dip in the input voltage.

Comment: There's a few things that don't seem to follow spec in your schematic. According to the [L293 datasheets](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/l293.pdf), Vcc1 should be at least 4.5V where you're supplying it with 3.3V. Furthermore, are you certain that Vin on the Arduino is producing >5V? Is the 5V rail actually 5V? A flat battery will cause it to run out of spec. The grounds on pins 4, 5, 12, 13 aren't all tied together to ground either.

Comment: Hang on, are you using a L293D or are you using a TA7291P? Your schematic doesn't seem to match your question

Comment: "I tried with separate power sources, but the problem's still there." - If the motors are powered from a separate battery then it should not brown out. You might have a 'ground loop' (motor current flowing though shared ground wire), or a software bug, or a loose connection. Make the Arduino flash an LED at regular intervals to prove that it is still alive, and turn on the Watchdog timer to reset the Arduino if it locks up for any reason.

Comment: @tangrs Sorry, I'm using both, and this time (I'm making 8 so 6 of these) I'm using L293D. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @BruceAbbott wait, but isn't it crucial to connect the ground pins of the motor driver to the ground of the Arduino, since we're connecting digital pins to the motor driver and the circuit isn't complete if I don't connect the grounds?

Comment: You must connect the grounds together, but avoid using a common wire for both batteries. If the batteries are wired as shown in your schematic it should be good (but you said "I use 4 1.5V batteries to power the entire thing" so I wasn't sure if the schematic was accurate). If using a single battery it should be wired to the motor driver first, then to the Arduino. That way motor current does not go through the Arduino's ground wires.

Comment: @BruceAbbott sorry for the confusion. I fixed it. Still, I can't find the reason though.....

Comment: @tangrs When I used the TA7291P with enough Vcc1it still had problems...

Comment: I am pretty much in agreement with @BruceAbbott. Again, what input voltages are you seeing when you measure the battery packs? It could be the batteries are too flat to power the Arduino properly. The only other potential explanation I have is the EMI generated from the motors are killing the Arduino but this seems pretty unlikely.

Comment: ...and I still can't follow what chip you're using. Are you using the L293D or are you using the TA7291P? You seem to be using them interchangeably. It might also be worth uploading pictures of your breadboard. It could be a case of wiring something incorrectly.

Comment: Lastly, you absolutely must ensure your circuit is operating within the allowable conditions and connected correctly as specified in the data sheet. If not, it can mask problems and it becomes near-impossible to debug. For example, you didn't say whether you were actually feeding 5V to Vcc1 nor did you say whether you tied the grounds together on pin 4, 5, 12, 13 (your diagram says they're not connected). Are you sanity checking all voltages with a multimeter to ensure they're what you expect?

Comment: @tangrs the battery levels are ok; they're 5.56V(connected to Arduino Nano)and 5.43V(connected to motor driver). I'm using the L293D. And ok, I'll keep those in mind next time. Thanks for the advice. I'll upload the pictures of my breadboard; though I doubt it'll help because of the messy wires.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem if the car is not moving (i.e. wheels off the ground) so that the unreliable breadboard connections are not disturbed?

Comment: @tangrs I tinkered with the circuit a little bit (using the L293D motor driver) and I managed to get it working a little bit. (The car still stops receiving commands for no reason sometimes for about 10 seconds or so...) I think the main problem with my RC car is that the batteries are not entirely reliable. Are there any alternatives to power sources, like Li-Po batteries? What voltage (and current rating)do you recommend?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Sometimes. Sorry for the ambiguous answer, but the RC Car sometimes goes haywire and starts spinning faster than usual in a certain direction without any commands going to it regardless of whether with torque(on the ground) or without any torque(free rotation). I checked that there aren't any problems with the communication nor the software, so it must be a power source problem or a motor driver problem. Any advice?

Comment: @TrepidClaw0601 Could you build your circuit on a piece of stripboard (Veroboard) so that you have soldered connections? You can use DIP sockets for the DIP components, or turned-pin socket strips. Also, you could use LEDs (with series resistors) in place of the motors to eliminate the motors as the source of the problem.

Comment: @TrepidClaw0601 Keep in mind that the linear regulator on the Nano has a dropout voltage. Your input voltage should be higher or equal to 6V. Are you certain there's 5V coming out of the 5V pin? Otherwise, remove the battery on the Arduino side completely and power it from USB for testing.

Answer (score 1):

To add to my comment, it sounds like the Arduino is suffering a brownout condition. I think the correct term is actually called [voltage sag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_sag) but essentially it means a temporary drop in voltage due to high current draw and the internal resistance of the battery.

It's likely the batteries you are using are not able to deliver the instantaneous current required to drive the motors. What happens is when the motors are first switched on, they initially draw a very large current and causes the battery output voltage to dip. After a certain point, the Arduino senses a brown-out condition and shuts down.

Depending on how bad the brownout is, you might be able to get away by throwing on a huge capacitor close to the input of your Arduino (after the voltage regulator which I presume you have). Hopefully that will tide over the initial high current draw.

Otherwise, you can try having separate power sources. One dedicated to the Arduino and the other dedicated to driving the motors. I haven't looked into your motor drivers but this configuration is supported by most drivers I've seen and used. They'll usually have two power inputs on the drivers: one for logic level voltage input and one for power input.

If you want to share a single power source, consider using a battery that is able to deliver high currents. You can look on websites like HobbyKing for lithium-ion batteries that can deliver high currents. Do read up on how to handle li-ion batteries if you decide to go this route though.

Without seeing your circuit or any oscilloscope pictures of the power rail, there's not much else I can suggest at this point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried with separate power sources, but the problem's still there. Sadly, I don't use a voltage regulator or a resistor. Do you think adding a resistor (or the voltage regulator) will help kill the voltage sag?

Comment: I would recommend putting up schematics of what you have tried or what you have at the moment. Do you have an oscilloscope that you can use to see the voltage fluctuations?

Comment: I also have no idea what you mean by adding a resistor or voltage regulator. Please add schematics!

Comment: Ok. I'll make one right now.

Comment: I added the schematics. Thanks for the help. And no, I don't have a oscilloscope.

Answer (score 0):

It must be noted that L293d motor driver is capable of delivering only 1A current per channel and L298n is capable of delivering 2A current per channel.Such amount of current may not be sufficient to drive your motors.So,try changing to a high current output motor driver. Hope it works.

Comment: A better driver is only likely to make the problem worse by increasing the battery sag and possibly radio interference.  In terms of performance (which is not the issue asked about) both the L293 and L298 and all such Darlington bridges are horribly unsuitable choices.  An FET bridge should be used and the crude 433 OOK radio replaced with a 2.4 GHz FSK one.

Comment: It has been said by the author of questions that even after changing the battery to 12 volts it doesn't work. So it may be possible that motor driver is not supplying enough current to motors.I have one case of past in my mind where when I connected LED's in place of motors by L298n motor driver,it worked fine but on connecting motors (which takes about 10A of current on average)it worked abnormally. So here,we can try changing to a high power motor driver.

Comment: No, you fundamentally misunderstand the nature of the failure they are reporting.  What they are saying is that the motors spin, but that then control fails.  This indicates that lack of power to the motors is *not the problem* but rather than the motors cause *failure of control*, either due to loading the battery below the needed voltage or due to generating radio interference.  A better driver would only increase the degree to which the motors can load the battery making that problem worse.  And it could quite well make RFI worse as well. **Your suggestion cannot solve the problem**

Comment: And further your proposed L298 is pretty much just as unwise a choice as the L293 would be, because in still being an antiquated and lossy Darlington device it's just a *bigger* version of the same *bad idea*.  You might also note hat the question has been abandoned for two years - in reality it should probably be removed from the site.